# Ubuntu suspend works only once through lid close

Tags: 12.10, suspend, asus, sleep

My system is ASUS N56VJ. The suspend feature works the first time if I sudpend by closing the lid/or specifically selecting to suspend form the settings menu(top right gear button).Lateron it just does not suspend..

Secondly if i press the hardware power button and choose to suspend from the poped up menu, i can suspend as many times i want.. same is the case if i suspend using

> sudo pm-sudpend

it suspends everytime.

the difference in the way suspend happens can be juged by the output of

> acpi_listen

while suspending using the above different options.

i have logged the **acpi_listen** optput as:

```
 1. button/power PWRF 00000080 00000001 @@@@SUCCESS (using power button)
 2. button/power PWRF 00000080 00000002 @@@@SUCCESS (using power button)
 3. button/lid LID 00000080 00000001    @@@@SUCCESS First Time! (closing the lid)
   video GFX0 00000080 00000000     @@@@ comes up when lid is opened
 4. button/lid LID 00000080 00000002    @@@@ Failure! 
   video GFX0 00000080 00000000     @@@@ comes automatically as suspend fails
   button/lid LID 00000080 00000003 @@@@ and this follows immediatelly (not sure why this comes two times)
   video GFX0 00000080 00000000     @@@@ and this too.
 5. button/power PWRF 00000080 00000003 @@@@ Failure! now suspend from power button fails too until reboot
 6. button/power PWRF 00000080 00000004 @@@@ Again Failure! now suspend from power button fails too until reboot
```

the complete dmesg log is attached with the important messages posted here synced with above 6 attempts to suspend:

1) Using Power button **SUCCESS**

```
[  571.919159] systemd-logind[2562]: execute_shutdown_or_sleep: failed to call org.freedesktop.systemd1, using fallback: Unknown unit: suspend.target
[  571.919171] systemd-logind[2562]: execute_shutdown_or_sleep_fallback: Running command '/usr/sbin/pm-suspend' for unit suspend.target
[  571.991180] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
[  572.055734] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: wolopts = 0
[  572.055744] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: wol-ctrl=0
[  572.133063] init: anacron main process (3643) killed by TERM signal
[  572.226866] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[  572.288292] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  572.303877] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  572.320090] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  572.327601] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  572.327677] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  572.327797] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  572.327877] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  572.346136] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending fbcon...
[  572.346139] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending display...
[  572.346146] nouveau  [     DRM] unpinning framebuffer(s)...
[  572.346268] nouveau  [     DRM] evicting buffers...                             @@@@button/power PWRF 00000080 00000001 SUCCESS
[  572.352651] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending client object trees...
[  572.994632] ACPI: Cannot transition to non-D0 state from D3
[  573.362177] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1043.529 msecs
[  573.362293] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.115 msecs
[  573.378190] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  573.394087] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  573.426046] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 63.844 msecs
[  573.426324] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  573.542073] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  573.591976] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  573.693576] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[  573.797410] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[  573.901256] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[  574.005102] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[  574.108944] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[  574.109381] Broke affinity for irq 16
[  574.109398] Broke affinity for irq 23
[  574.212790] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[  574.213186] Broke affinity for irq 17
[  574.316634] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[  574.316959] Extended CMOS year: 2000
[  574.318088] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
```

2) Using Power button **SUCCESS**

```
[  584.303427] systemd-logind[2562]: execute_shutdown_or_sleep: failed to call org.freedesktop.systemd1, using fallback: Unknown unit: suspend.target
[  584.303440] systemd-logind[2562]: execute_shutdown_or_sleep_fallback: Running command '/usr/sbin/pm-suspend' for unit suspend.target
[  584.423757] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
[  584.507374] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: wolopts = 0
[  584.507382] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: wol-ctrl=0
[  584.589690] init: anacron main process (4182) killed by TERM signal
[  584.632872] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[  584.724279] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  584.740073] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  584.756286] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  584.763627] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  584.763669] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  584.763733] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  584.782901] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending fbcon...
[  584.782904] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending display...
[  584.782910] nouveau  [     DRM] unpinning framebuffer(s)...
[  584.782993] nouveau  [     DRM] evicting buffers...                               @@@@button/power PWRF 00000080 00000002 SUCCESS
[  584.783572] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending client object trees...
[  584.871706] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  585.414888] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D3hot
[  585.906247] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1151.563 msecs
[  585.906374] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.125 msecs
[  585.922217] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  585.938277] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  585.970095] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 63.814 msecs
[  585.970349] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  586.106052] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  586.159958] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  586.261555] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[  586.365404] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[  586.469246] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[  586.573091] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[  586.676938] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[  586.677314] Broke affinity for irq 16
[  586.677331] Broke affinity for irq 23
[  586.780778] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[  586.781184] Broke affinity for irq 17
[  586.884624] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[  586.884915] Extended CMOS year: 2000
[  586.886032] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
```

3) Closing lid the first time **SUCCESS**

```
[  602.205758] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:1e:40:f1:9b:07 by local choice (reason=3)
[  602.218589] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  602.228761] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  602.228768] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  602.228771] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  602.228774] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  602.228777] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  602.228779] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  602.228782] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  603.122041] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
[  603.187242] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: wolopts = 0
[  603.187253] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: wol-ctrl=0
[  603.262392] init: anacron main process (4734) killed by TERM signal
[  603.755180] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[  603.826503] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  603.842341] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  603.858571] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  603.858861] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  603.858890] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  603.858917] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  603.858939] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  603.877540] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending fbcon...
[  603.877543] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending display...
[  603.877550] nouveau  [     DRM] unpinning framebuffer(s)...
[  603.877651] nouveau  [     DRM] evicting buffers...                                    @@@@button/lid LID 00000080 00000001 SUCCESS First Time!
[  603.878552] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending client object trees...                      @@@@video GFX0 00000080 00000000 this comes when lid is opened.
[  604.509166] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D3hot
[  604.900677] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1043.548 msecs
[  604.900802] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.124 msecs
[  604.916647] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  604.932704] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  604.964522] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 63.813 msecs
[  604.964776] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  605.092497] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  605.148262] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  605.251990] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[  605.355838] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[  605.459678] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[  605.563528] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[  605.563896] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 02
[  605.667372] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[  605.667742] Broke affinity for irq 16
[  605.667758] Broke affinity for irq 23
[  605.771214] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[  605.771653] Broke affinity for irq 17
[  605.771663] Broke affinity for irq 41
[  605.875059] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[  605.875387] Extended CMOS year: 2000
[  605.876506] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
```

4) Closing lid the second time,**Failure!**

```
[  628.733794] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:1e:40:f1:9b:07 by local choice (reason=3)
[  628.756062] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  628.766261] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  628.766267] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  628.766270] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  628.766273] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  628.766275] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  628.766278] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  628.766280] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  629.644794] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
[  629.774430] init: anacron main process (5394) killed by TERM signal
[  630.270388] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[  630.709167] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.03 seconds) done.
[  630.740952] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  630.757167] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  630.757446] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  630.757473] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  630.757536] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  630.757542] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  630.776492] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending fbcon...
[  630.776495] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending display...
[  630.776505] nouveau  [     DRM] unpinning framebuffer(s)...
[  630.776586] nouveau  [     DRM] evicting buffers...                                        @@@@button/lid LID 00000080 00000002 Failure!
[  630.777114] alx 0000:04:00.0: PHY SPD/DPLX unresolved :ffff                                @@@@video GFX0 00000080 00000000 comes automatically as suspend fails
[  630.777116] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: shutown err(ffffffea)                                   @@@@button/lid LID 00000080 00000003 and this follows immediatelly
[  630.777117] alx 0000:04:00.0: shutdown fail in suspend -5                                  @@@@video GFX0 00000080 00000000 and this too.
[  630.777129] pci_pm_suspend(): alx_suspend+0x0/0x90 [alx] returns -5
[  630.777132] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x140 returns -5
[  630.777134] PM: Device 0000:04:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -5
[  630.777159] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending client object trees...
[  631.407447] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D3hot
[  631.819647] PM: Some devices failed to suspend
[  631.819756] mei 0000:00:16.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[  631.819834] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[  631.819835] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[  631.819859] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
[  631.834608] nouveau  [     DRM] re-enabling device...
[  631.834631] nouveau  [     DRM] resuming client object trees...
[  631.834635] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] running init tables
[  631.834653] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  631.834675] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[  631.961131] nouveau  [     DRM] resuming display...
[  633.231816] PM: resume of devices complete after 1414.976 msecs
[  633.232032] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  633.247959] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[  633.247962] video LNXVIDEO:01: Restoring backlight state
[  633.607031] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p on, RC6pp off
[  633.730762] init: anacron main process (5644) killed by TERM signal
[  633.789826] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
[  633.933085] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  635.963373] wlan0: authenticate with 00:1e:40:f1:9b:07
[  635.967378] wlan0: capabilities/regulatory prevented using AP HT/VHT configuration, downgraded
[  635.967476] wlan0: send auth to 00:1e:40:f1:9b:07 (try 1/3)
[  635.969645] wlan0: authenticated
[  635.969866] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  635.969875] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  635.969880] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  635.970308] wlan0: associate with 00:1e:40:f1:9b:07 (try 1/3)
[  635.973042] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:1e:40:f1:9b:07 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  635.973102] wlan0: associated
[  635.973115] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

5) Again using power button, **Failure** from now on

```
[  692.762199] systemd-logind[2562]: execute_shutdown_or_sleep: failed to call org.freedesktop.systemd1, using fallback: Unknown unit: suspend.target
[  692.762212] systemd-logind[2562]: execute_shutdown_or_sleep_fallback: Running command '/usr/sbin/pm-suspend' for unit suspend.target
[  692.884566] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
[  692.997459] init: anacron main process (6011) killed by TERM signal
[  693.265267] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[  693.364485] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  693.380198] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  693.396500] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  693.403715] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  693.403725] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  693.403810] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  693.403816] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  693.423382] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending fbcon...
[  693.423385] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending display...
[  693.423393] nouveau  [     DRM] unpinning framebuffer(s)...
[  693.423515] nouveau  [     DRM] evicting buffers...              @@@@button/power PWRF 00000080 00000003 Failure now suspend from power button fails too until reboot
[  693.423995] alx 0000:04:00.0: PHY SPD/DPLX unresolved :ffff
[  693.423997] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: shutown err(ffffffea)
[  693.423997] alx 0000:04:00.0: shutdown fail in suspend -5
[  693.424009] pci_pm_suspend(): alx_suspend+0x0/0x90 [alx] returns -5
[  693.424012] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x140 returns -5
[  693.424014] PM: Device 0000:04:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -5
[  693.424162] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending client object trees...
[  694.050776] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D3hot
[  694.416394] PM: Some devices failed to suspend
[  694.416486] mei 0000:00:16.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[  694.416565] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[  694.416567] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[  694.416568] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
[  694.430148] nouveau  [     DRM] re-enabling device...
[  694.430174] nouveau  [     DRM] resuming client object trees...
[  694.430177] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] running init tables
[  694.430180] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  694.430241] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[  694.487664] Extended CMOS year: 2000
[  694.556953] nouveau  [     DRM] resuming display...
[  695.495880] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p on, RC6pp off
[  695.844630] PM: resume of devices complete after 1431.073 msecs
[  695.844881] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  695.859473] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[  695.859477] video LNXVIDEO:01: Restoring backlight state
[  696.041741] init: anacron main process (6265) killed by TERM signal
[  696.085882] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
```

6) Again using power button **Failure Continues!**

```
[  701.427151] systemd-logind[2562]: execute_shutdown_or_sleep: failed to call org.freedesktop.systemd1, using fallback: Unknown unit: suspend.target
[  701.427164] systemd-logind[2562]: execute_shutdown_or_sleep_fallback: Running command '/usr/sbin/pm-suspend' for unit suspend.target
[  701.563159] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
[  701.703776] init: anacron main process (6461) killed by TERM signal
[  701.747261] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[  701.807565] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  701.823449] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[  701.839658] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  701.848980] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  701.848998] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  701.849061] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  701.867981] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending fbcon...
[  701.867990] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending display...
[  701.868001] nouveau  [     DRM] unpinning framebuffer(s)...
[  701.868084] nouveau  [     DRM] evicting buffers...             @@@@button/power PWRF 00000080 00000004 Failure now suspend from power button fails too until reboot
[  701.868611] alx 0000:04:00.0: PHY SPD/DPLX unresolved :ffff
[  701.868612] alx 0000:04:00.0 eth0: shutown err(ffffffea)
[  701.868613] alx 0000:04:00.0: shutdown fail in suspend -5
[  701.868626] pci_pm_suspend(): alx_suspend+0x0/0x90 [alx] returns -5
[  701.868629] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x140 returns -5
[  701.868632] PM: Device 0000:04:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -5
[  701.868636] nouveau  [     DRM] suspending client object trees...
[  701.918459] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  702.497965] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D3hot
[  702.934403] PM: Some devices failed to suspend
[  702.934535] mei 0000:00:16.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[  702.934604] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
[  702.934605] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[  702.934606] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[  702.949041] nouveau  [     DRM] re-enabling device...
[  702.949070] nouveau  [     DRM] resuming client object trees...
[  702.949074] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] running init tables
[  702.949173] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  702.949203] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[  703.075739] nouveau  [     DRM] resuming display...
[  704.384265] PM: resume of devices complete after 1452.746 msecs
[  704.384483] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  704.402378] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[  704.402382] video LNXVIDEO:01: Restoring backlight state
[  704.465993] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p on, RC6pp off
[  704.551039] init: anacron main process (6712) killed by TERM signal
[  704.597116] thinkpad_ec: no ThinkPad embedded controller!
```

[full dmesg log](http://pastebin.com/MdFW5gBM)

**Important points** 1) what i can fetch out here is that when i use the power button to suspend from the popped  up menu, the command executed to suspend is

> execute_shutdown_or_sleep

while closing from the lid im not sure what command gets executed for sleep from the above logs.

Secondly, i am only prompted for a password on waking up when i do that by closing the lid/or selecting suspend from the power menu in top right corner,and not when i do it using sudo **pm-suspend** or by using the suspend option in popped up menu on pressing h/w power button.Maybe this is important?

Thanks.

few more inputs..

1)My Machine info [ASUS N56VJ](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N56VJ/#specifications)

2)output for cat /proc/acpi/wakeup

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
P0P1      S4    *disabled  
PEG0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
PEG1      S4    *disabled  
PEG2      S4    *disabled  
PEG3      S4    *disabled  
XHC1      S3    *disabled  
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
USB1      S3    *disabled  
USB2      S3    *disabled  
USB3      S3    *disabled  
USB4      S3    *disabled  
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
USB5      S3    *disabled  
USB6      S3    *disabled  
USB7      S3    *disabled  
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
RP03      S4    *disabled  
RP05      S4    *disabled  
RP06      S4    *disabled  
RP07      S4    *disabled  
RP08      S4    *disabled  
WLAN      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
RP04      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
GLAN      S4    *disabled  
LAN2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:04:00.0
XHC   S3    *disabled  
SLPB      S4    *enabled
```

So i guess suspending it from the closing of lid/using the settings menu,something erratic happens that makes the system not suspend any more.

My current OS: ubuntu 13.04 BETA 3.8.0-15-generic. though i tested with 12.10 as well and the observations are identical.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1130037

Workaround in #23

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but i cant test it as of now.. as my notebook has been bricked!.. will test it when it comes to life. :)

Answer (score -1):

I have an Asus n56vz, quite similar to yours, and the answer [Helmo](https://askubuntu.com/users/152309/helmo) gave worked for me. I actually used the code from [workaround #27 in the thread he provided](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1130037):

Add SUSPEND_MODULES="alx" to /etc/pm/config.d/modules

Now suspend seems to work each time, regardless of how I suspend, pressing the power button, going through the menu, or the fn + f1 key.

Good luck!